# Python and Beautiful soup - getting values and saving them in a text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have sort of a XML file contains many records of relevant info that looks like this

```
<file>
<record>
<type>a</type>
<number>2</number>
</record>

<record>
<type>b</type>
<number>9</number>
</record>
```

etc.

I want BS to read all the XML file and to give me the results by columns :

a  2

b  9
etc

EDIT

Thank you all for pitching in. I installed xml parser and I'm using bs4 xml mode. I don't get the error anymore however I get :

a  b

2  9

instead of

a  2

b  9

New code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('file.xml'),"xml")

with open('output.txt') as f: 
   for type1,number in (soup.findall('type'),soup.findall('number')):
     f.write ('%s\t%s\n' % (type1.text, number.text))
```

2nd EDIT :

If I add a 3rd record in the XML file, I get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multixmlsript.py", line 8, in 
    for type1,number in (soup.findAll('type'),soup.findAll('number')):
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: BeautifulSoup is better suited for HTML, not XML. At the very least install `lxml` and use `BeautifulSoup(file, parser='xml')` to have BS adjust behaviour properly.

Comment: Show us the code that actually throws that `TypeError`, or at the very least the full traceback. The error message doesn't match what you have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(open('path/to/file'))

with open('/path/to/output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(soup.findAll('type'))):
        f.write ('%s\t%s\n' % (soup.findAll('type')[i].text, soup.findAll('number')[i].text))
```

You have used the `BeautifulSoup` it is for HTML. But you need to use `BeautifulStoneSoup` for xml. I hope this will be help you.

Comment: thanks. Now all values are in the output but it puts the type on one single line and number on a different line.

Comment: is there any way to store them by columns?